# how to load multiple cell from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have one table that I want load from xib two cell.
in UITableViewCell xib file I have two cell (two part with tag 100 and 200) that I want load first view (first cell) in first row and load second cell in second row.
both cells are in xib file like this:
[image: two cell from xib]

this is my code :

```
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",topLevelObject);
            cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@",cell);
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        CustomCell *cell2 = (CustomCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
        if (cell2 == nil)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                    cell2 = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell2;
    }
    return nil;        
}
```

I don't know where is my wrong because when run code I see only first cell in tableView

Comment: For display tow different tableview cells. You need to create two different of tableview cell subcalss.

Answer (score 0):

You are using first cell from XIB at section = 0 
    cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:0];
so, in the same way you can get the second cell at index 1 for the section 1
    cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:1];